# How to assign a unique IDs to the mapped portion of an image & link it with database

Tags: jquery, html, database, google-maps, image-processing

I have created an image map of a floor plan of a building. Now I want to store the mapped portions of image with each map having its unique id. and then store the ids in to mysql database table. so that I can highlight (or place a marker on) a portion of the image just by specifying its location ID from database table.

Comment: This appears to be more a server-side than a client-side question. Could you please clarify, what do you want to store?

Comment: What I want to do is to create a web interface in which if a user searches for an "employee name" lets say John. The website should retrieve a row of John from mysql database that contains a column of his location id (lets say 10). it should then highlight the portion of the image (John's location ID) in which the user is currently present. A kind of employee tracking system, in which we can see the current location of an employee based on his database entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requirement can certainly be met.

In summary, the component parts of the application will be something like this :

- Storage of user data: database
- Storage of map area coordinates: database
- Retrieval of user data and map coordinates from database: PHP*/SQL
- Composition of document (including image maps): PHP*
- Client-server communication: (jQuery) AJAX
- Area highlighting: (jQuery) [MapHighlight plugin](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/)

* *typically*

You really need to have a go at writing some code, then ask again when you run into difficulty.

Comment: @Beetroor-BeetrootThanks for the information. Uptill now I am done with highlighting areas of the mapped portion on mouse hover, what I really want is to highlight only that specific portion for which the user id is stored in database row. for e.g if user searches for John and he has his location id =a1 then the jquery should only highlight  the map with id=a1. any suggestion how?

Comment: Faizan, are you using the `MapHighlight` plugin or something else?

Comment: Yes I am using this"jquery.maphilight.js" plugin, I am now done with the id highlighting, just now want to know how to embed php (to get row and column) with html (to tell jquery to highlight the location variable received from php).

Comment: You have three choices; (1) include the necessary data for all users in the page when it is served then run the application without further involvement of the server (2) fetch the necessary user data from the server using AJAX, once per search, or (3) refresh the whole page at every search.

Comment: Best answer for pointing about Maphighlight.