# How do I add markers/pointers on a mapped image

Tags: html, database, image, mapping, coordinates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to assign a unique IDs to the mapped portion of an image & link it with database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899332/how-to-assign-a-unique-ids-to-the-mapped-portion-of-an-image-link-it-with-data)

I have a simple building floor plan (jpg image) with rooms on it.It is a mapped image.
What I want is to add markers/pointers on specific rooms. lets say if user searches for "CR1" then a marker should be placed at mapped region of the image that represents CR1.
CR1 means Class Room 1.
Here is my code:

`<img src="UG ground.jpg" alt="UG" usemap="#mymap"/>
  <map name="mymap">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" href="mercur.htm">
  <area shape="poly" coords="549,272,489,334,534,377,594,316" href="www.msn.com" target="_top" alt="CR1" name="room-1">
  <area shape="poly" coords="578,244,621,201,662,240,622,286" href="#" alt="CR2">
  <area shape="poly" coords="665,155,624,201,669,244,711,200" href="#" alt="CR3">`

Comment: you asked this same question earlier today, and it was closed I believe...

Comment: But I didn't get the answer of what I am trying to acheive. It would be a great favor if you could help me with that.

Comment: You're going to want to use something that's more CADD oriented. Blender could help you build up the data files and references, for instance. At least depending on the size of the project. At my university, they generate all of that out of AutoCADD and 3D Max. But that's probably a costly solution.

Comment: Yes it is a costly solution , but I believe that it is easily possible  to do that using jquery,html php or mysql database. I don't know where to start. I have found this on web very similar to what I want to achieve.
http://jquery-image-map.ssdtutorials.com/